# How to download a directory from a storage account from the command line using the 'abfss://' uri

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

*ADLS* / *Azure Blobstore* provides URI's in the form like

> abfss://feed-pipeline-workspace@smy-storage-account.dfs.core.windows.net/my-user/my-parquet.parquet

Is there no tool available that can simply take that URI and download?  The `az cli` requires decomposing the path into various parts and in the end does not work due to various bugs.   I have also tried `azcopy copy` and run into a different set of problems. It is not clear how to decompose the `abfss` URI into a path that is functional for `azcopy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not clear how to decompose the `abfss` URI into a path that is functional for `azcopy`.

You can use the below command to download the parquet file from azure-data lake gen2 to the local folder.

**Command:**

```
azcopy copy "https://venkat098.dfs.core.windows.net/filesystem1/test/samplepar.parquet?<SAS-token>" "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\folder1" --recursive=true
```

Here,

- venkat098 = Storage account name
- filesystem1=container
- test/samplepar.parquet= folder+file.

You can get the SAS-token from your storage account through the portal.

*Portal ->Your storage account -> Shared access signature  -> check the container and object -> Click GenerateSAS.*

[image]

**Output:**

```
azcopy copy "https://venkat098.dfs.core.windows.net/filesystem1/test/samplepar.parquet?<SAS-token>" "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\folder1" --recursive=true

INFO: Scanning...
INFO: azcopy.exe: A newer version 10.18.1 is available to download

INFO: Any empty folders will be processed, because source and destination both support folders

Job 1e8dffa1-b6e3-5e4e-7a07-5axxxxxx has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\.azcopy\1e8dffa1-b6e3-5e4e-7a07-5a7d866f0c35.log

100.0 %, 1 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 1 Total,


Job 1e8dffa1-b6e3-5e4e-7a07-5xxxxxx summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0669
Number of File Transfers: 1
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 1
Number of Transfers Completed: 1
Number of Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 113629
Final Job Status: Completed
```

[image]

**Downloaded file:**
[image]

Comment: I have been unable to get `azcopy` to run from macos.  I can't verify this, but will upvote anyways

Comment: Hi @WestCoastProjects you can download azcopy in Macos by following this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy).